# When is a sum of products of two matrices and the transposes positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, transpose

Let $X$ and $Y$ be $n \times m$ matrices. The matrix
$$
A = X^TY + Y^TX
$$
will be a $m \times m$ square, symmetric matrix. Is it possible to say: i) when is $A$ is positive definite? and when it is ii) letting $A = Z^TZ$, can we express $Z$ in terms of $X$ and $Y$? I assume the two questions are related since the second would imply the first but I am not sure how to proceed.

Edit: the question came about as I want to show that $A$ in the sum
$$
A = X^TSY + Y^TSX
$$
where $S$ is a $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix, is positive definite. The presence of $S$ may make the problem simpler.

Comment: Let $X$ bet the 1x1 matrix (-1).  Let $Y$ be the 1x1 matrix (1).  Then $A$ = (-2) which is not positive definite.  You can also set $X=-I_n$ and $Y=I_n$ to get a similar result for $n$x$n$ matrices.

Comment: Thanks @irchans that is an obvious counterexample! I think I worded my question poorly, as I suspected it wasn't universally true but was interested in the cases when it might be true what one could say about the matrices. I have edited the question

Comment: I'm thinking along the line of $v^TAv=2<Xv,Yv>$ we need to find the condion of the minimum of this bilinear form being positive